# Rails Paperclip uploads numbers after url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, paperclip

Whenever I upload a file through paperclip the end of the URL gets kind of messed up, for instance, in stead of the expected URL

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/1/file.pdf
```

I get

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/1/file.pdf?1415287826
```

The url and path in my model are:

```
has_attached_file :file, url: "/assets/:id/:basename.pdf",
                         path: ":rails_root/public/assets/:id/:basename.pdf"
```

The actual file is not stored like this, this is only how the url looks using

```
<%= link_to "Open PDF", upload.file.url %>
```

It seems like an easy to fix problem but I just can't find the solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's timestamp for your file. It holds the time when your file was uploaded to the server: in this case `Time.at(1415287826) => 2014-11-06 15:30:26 +0000`

When you will download that file, it will be cached by the browser (images are cached by default, pdfs can be cached now if browser supports pdf rendering). With that timestamp if you upload a file with exactly the same name (so the same url will be generated), browser will not highlight that link as visited. As a result, if it's an image with the same name, its cached version will not be rendered, because browser will considers such link as not visited therefore not cached.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarifies a lot.